# How to cast(convert) string to blob? in ESQL?

Tags: messagebroker, ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

So i am reading an XML file from request note of flow.
And need to convert XML data to blob.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
CAST( MYLITTLESTRING AS BLOB CCSID InputRoot.Properties.CodedCharSetId)
```

Comment: It gives error such as like this: String is not of correct form for byte array. Must consist of only 0..9,a..f,A..Z

Comment: Something like this works though: CAST( MYLITTLESTRING AS BLOB CCSID InputRoot.Properties.CodedCharSetId)

Comment: Thanks @Piyush - CCSID is now included in answer.

Comment: The answer of PetterNordlander is right, but for an answer with a list of sources see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44944872/6679645). @PetterNordlander maybe you can provide your answers with sources in the future :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you receive messages from both ASCII and EBCDIC based platforms you should include a CCSID often based on the inbound messages CodedCharSetId.

```
DECLARE StaticValueBlob BLOB CAST('StaticValue' AS BLOB CCSID InputRoot.Properties.CodedCharSetId);
```

If you are looking to get the whole XML document as a BLOB then you will want to use the ResetContentDescriptor Node instead.