# How to convert String to BLOB in ESQL?

Tags: ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

It should be as simple as

> ```
>   SET OutputRoot.BLOB.BLOB = CAST(MYSTRING AS BLOB);
> ```

But when I do that IIB Throws an error

> An attempt was made to cast the character string ''ABC'' to a byte string, but the string was of the wrong format.  There must be an even number of hexadecimal digits (0-9, a-f, A-F).

Answer (score 2):

As you figured out, the Syntax of the **CAST-function** you need here is

```
CAST( <source_expression> AS <DataType> CCSID <expression> )
```

so in your code it is

```
CAST( MYSTRING AS BLOB CCSID 1208 )
```

> The CCSID parameter is used only for conversions to or from one of the string data types. Use the CCSID parameter to specify the code page of the source or target string. [[Source](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ak05610_.htm)]

So with the **Coded character set identifiers** (CCSID) you define the [code page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ac00408_.htm). For example *1208* is the CCSID for *UTF-8 with IBM PUA*. You can see a list of IBMs CCSIDs [here](https://www-01.ibm.com/software/globalization/ccsid/ccsid_registered.html).

If you want to get informations on this topic in more detail you can check the IIB documentation for [Version 9.0.0](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ak05610_.htm) or [Version 10.0.0](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ak05610_.htm).

Answer (score 1):

In my case I needed to change it to  AS BLOB CCSID 1208
I need to read up on what CCSID means now.